# OrientDB Select query with multiple conditions

Tags: select, orientdb

I am beginner in OrientDB and I have a scenario as below,
[image]

I want to select all the permissions "Adrian" has on "Workspace A"
I can see from the graph that "Adrian" will have all the permissions but I am not able to form the Select query in OrientDB for that.
The classes are as below,

[image]

I think the query should look like below but it doesn't return any result,

```
SELECT name, out('isOfType').in('ofType').out('hasA').name as permission 
FROM resource 
WHERE name = 'Workspace A'  and
      out('isOfType').in('OfType').in('hasARole').name = 'Adrian'
```

Comment: Can you add which are the classes of your domain?

Comment: Did you have any luck in solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

graph operators return collections, so you have to use CONTAINS instead of =

eg.

```
 SELECT name, out('isOfType').in('ofType').out('hasA').name as permission 
 FROM resource 
 WHERE name = 'Workspace A'  and
  out('isOfType').in('OfType').in('hasARole').name CONTAINS 'Adrian'
```